# Why last row deleted when refresh page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I refresh page table row deleted and last query deleted when I click on any delete button of other row. Why is this happened?
This is table which I displayed

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table= 'wp_contact_form';
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $table" );

if(!empty($result)){

foreach ( $result as $print ) {  
        
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $print->id;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->names;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->emails;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->gender;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->age;?></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Edit" id="" name="update"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="delete" id="delete" name="delete"></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
} 
?>
```

this is delete query

```
$id= $print->id;
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $result = $wpdb->delete($table, array('id' => $id));
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
}
```

error screenshot - https://prnt.sc/wdg3xv

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying which ID should be deleted if $_POST['delete'] is set, right now you're asking WP to just delete something.

You need to wrap your elements in a form and add a field that contains the exact ID of the element you want to delete, like this:

```
<td>
  <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
  <input type="hidden" name="targetItem" value="<?php echo $print->id;?>" />
</td>
```

Then in your PHP use that field's ID to delete it from the DB:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']))
    $result = $wpdb->delete($table, array('id' => $_POST['targetItem']));
```

Comment: no it's not working here is screenshot - https://prnt.sc/wdjsak

Comment: did you change your "delete" button to be the hidden item? you need both the <input type="submit" value="delete" id="delete" name="delete"> AND the hidden field in the form